# What is a constricting actuator called?

Tags: mechanisms, terminology

I'm looking for search terms, I'd like to find something **like an electric [hose clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hose_clamp)** - a high-force, low-power, low-speed, motorized constricting mechanism.

[image]

I already googled some terms various combinations of `constricting` `constrictor` `mechanism` `mechanical` `actuator` `squeezing` `-snake`, have not been fruitful. **Is there a term I am missing?**

Comment: Explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a **throttle**. More generally it is a **control system**.

There is a vast range of literature on throttles so you could ask for an aviation throttle, a engine throttle, or basically anything that involves regulated flow.

Answer (score 0):

Ive never heard of a motorised verson, but thats called a jubilee clip?

Comment: This is a comment.